# How to allocate video-card memory directly in Windows?

Tags: windows, bitmap, directx

I am required to allocate bitmap in video-card memory in a project in Windows. Because the project use other 2d library other than GDI, so CreateCompatibleBitmap is useless.

Then i figure out a method using DX, here is my code:

```
if(FAILED(g_D3DDevice->CreateVertexBuffer(10240 * 1024, 0,  
        D3DFVF_VERTEX, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &g_VertexBuffer,  
        NULL))) return false;  

    // Fill the vertex buffer.  
    void *ptr;  

    if(FAILED(g_VertexBuffer->Lock(0, 1024 * 10240,  
        (void**)&ptr, 0))) return false;  

    //do something...
    //printf("ptf = %x\n", ptr);
    //memcpy(ptr, objData, sizeof(objData));  
    g_VertexBuffer->Unlock();
```

It works well so far. But are there any sideeffect?

Comment: If you really need to have the .bmp in video-card memory (why not in regular?) this will get you the result you want but you will need to unlock the vertexBuffer when writing information to it.

Comment: Why would you store it in a vertexbuffer when there are texture/surface objects available which are specifically for storing bitmap data?

Comment: @jcoder: I do not know how. I just find it on the internet.

Comment: What do you need to do with this bitmap once its in GPU memory?

Comment: @ananthonline: the bitmap is just like bitmap as CreateCompatibleBitmap, the 2d-library need to draw it frequently, just as GDI draws the DDB. The video-card driver/OS implement the GDI-draw functions, but the 3rd 2d-library does not has this power.

Comment: If the 2D library you're using doesn't optimize the storage location, how would storing the bitmap in video memory let this library draw faster? This doesn't make any sense to me at all. Also - how do you pass a pointer to GPU memory to this library? A VertexBuffer is not really a pointer to the memory location, you know. It is an API/Driver specific handle.

Comment: Like what i said, i am required to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Sideeffect:

- You will have to unlock the VertexBuffer every single time you want to write or read to it
- Slower then normal memory

Aside from this sideeffect make sure to check this process went sucessfull as video card out of memory does not supply the most "user obvious"-kind of error.

As for why it would be slow: by putting it into your video card memory you will have to request access to the vertex each time you want to write/read, which is slower then actually accessing it right away in regular memory.

Comment: could i just lock one time and use it as regular memory. When i do not need it, unlock and release it one time.

Comment: @Jichao I'm pretty sure you can do that, as long as you have no intention of writing to it.

Comment: I definitely need to write to it.

Comment: @Jichao I meant like you currently do it: write the bmp to it, use it a few times in your program, release it

Answer (score 2):

I can't imagine any legitimate reason to want to do this but in general it is not possible anyway. Windows PCs have a wide range of hardware and many do not even have a concept of separate video memory. For those that do the performance characteristics are not guaranteed which is why Direct3D has lots of ways of indicating to the driver your intended usage so that the driver can decide where best to locate resources (amongst other things, like how best to lay them out in memory) rather than providing ways for you to specify 'in video memory' and other concepts that are not consistently defined across different hardware types.

If as you say your boss asked you to do this it seems like a case study in bad project management - specifying the implementation details of what to do rather than specifying the project goals and leaving the engineer tasked with implementation to figure out how best to achieve them. Presumably the real goal here is to improve performance of some task or operation. Almost certainly what you're doing is not the best way to achieve that.

Comment: :Actually my boss said there was a trend that the pc's resolution would increase, and the size of the bitmap would increase and if we allocate too much bitmaps, the OS need to switch out/from pagefile. This cause performance problem, so he think it is better to use video card memory.gTg

Comment: Would you like to ask ur boss "Are you willing to use VidMem as RAM? If so, every time that needs to be locked unlocked"


I would say buy more RAM than screwing yourself and users!